# Break down date by month and the week of each month using Sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

What I need is break down the date by month and the week of that month. For example, for `'2020-01-06'` I want to see `January, 1 week`, or for  `'2020-01-13'`, I want to see `January, 2nd week`. 
Here is the code that wrote:

```
.....
distinct t1.incidentid
,t1.status as [CW_Staus],
t1.title
,t1.createddatetime
,datename(MM,t1.createddatetime) as Month
,datename(ww,t1.createddatetime) as Week
.....
```

Now, what I see is this
 [image]

However, with the start of each month, I want to restart the week count. for `'2020-02-01'`, I want to see `Feb, 1week`. 
What am I missing in the code?
Thank you

Comment: How do *you* define the first week of the month? If Monday is March 31st, does the week belongs to March or April? And what if the 31st of March is a Friday instead?

Answer (score 1):

You could try taking the day of the month and divide by 7:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.incidentid,
    t1.status AS [CW_Staus],
    t1.title,
    t1.createddatetime,
    DATENAME(MM, t1.createddatetime) AS Month,
    1 + ((DATEPART(day, t1.createddatetime)-1) / 7) AS WeekOfMonth
...
```

Keep in mind that the above logic assumes that you actually want to reset the count of weeks for each month, at the start of each month.  More typically, there are ISO standard ways of counting the week in the year.  There are edge cases to be considered, as any given year may not have an whole number of weeks.

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen, why are you adding 1 to it?

Comment: @nina_dev I add one in that formula because the first week is 1, not 0.  Keep in mind that the first _day_ of any month would be `1 + ((1-1) / 7)`, which becomes 1.  Try out the formula to see if it works.